# Bulk insert/update using R to mongoDB

Tags: r, mongodb

I am trying to insert a lot of data (millions of documents) into mongodb using R from a variety of data frames which I will obtain at different times.

Each data frame will have the same primary id, but can have the same or different attributes.

If the record exists, I would like to add any new attributes and append any existing ones. If the record doesn't exist, I would like to create it.

Is this possible in R efficiently? I have tried to use the wonderful mongolite package, but the insert option fails because of duplicate records existing.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Iain

```
id<-LETTERS[1:5]
value1<-paste0("value1_",letters[1:5])
value2<-paste0("value2_",letters[1:5])
value3<-paste0("additional_value_1",letters[1:5])
df1<-as.data.frame(cbind(id,value1))
df2<-as.data.frame(cbind(id,value2))
df3<-as.data.frame(cbind(id,value3))

colnames(df1)<-c('_id','value1')
colnames(df2)<-c('_id','value2')
colnames(df3)<-c('_id','value1')

desired_value1<-paste0( "[",paste(paste0("'",value1,"'"),paste0("'",value3,"'"),sep=","),"]")
df4<-cbind(id,desired_value1,value2)
df4<-as.data.frame(cbind(id,desired_value1,value2))
colnames(df4)<-c("_id","value1","value2")
```

Comment: Sorry, should be fixed now. It is the concatenation of value 1 and value 3. df4 shows the values that should be in mongodb after inserting df1, df2 and df3 in order. df1 and df3 both contain data value1 and so should be appended together rather than overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Note

This answer uses `library(rmongodb)`, which is no longer supported nor on Cran.

---

This answer will partly depend on how you're getting your 'new' data.frames. I also can't answer the **efficiently** part either without knowing your setup and size of data, but hopefully this will get you started. Plus, I've found inserting/retreiving millions of records into mongo from R to be quite slow.

One way of doing this would be for every new `data.frame` you get, bring back the matching records into R and 'join/update' them, then update the database for just those documents, while appending the new data using an `update / upsert` query.

I also use [`library(rmongodb)`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmongodb/index.html) for most of my r-mongodb work

Slightly modifying your data to use `id` instead of `_id`:

```
id<-LETTERS[1:5]
value1<-paste0("value1_",letters[1:5])
value2<-paste0("value2_",letters[1:5])
value3<-paste0("additional_value_1",letters[1:5])
df1<-as.data.frame(cbind(id,value1), stringsAsFactors = F)  ## removed factor levels
df2<-as.data.frame(cbind(id,value2), stringsAsFactors = F)
df3<-as.data.frame(cbind(id,value3), stringsAsFactors = F)

colnames(df1)<-c('id','value1')
colnames(df2)<-c('id','value2')
colnames(df3)<-c('id','value1')

desired_value1<-paste0( "[",paste(paste0("'",value1,"'"),paste0("'",value3,"'"),sep=","),"]")
df4<-cbind(id,desired_value1,value2)
df4<-as.data.frame(cbind(id,desired_value1,value2))
colnames(df4)<-c("_id","value1","value2")
```

The first step is to insert it into the database

```
library(rmongodb)  ## my preferred r mongodb package 
library(jsonlite)  ## for viewing/checking results 
library(data.table) ## for fast rbind & data frame manipulation

mongo <- mongo.create()
mongo.is.connected(mongo)
# [1] TRUE

db <- "test"
coll <- "test"

bs <- mongo.bson.from.df(df1)
ns <- paste0(db, ".", coll)

## insert.batch - insert each 'row' of the df as a document
mongo.insert.batch(mongo = mongo, 
                   ns = ns, 
                   lst = bs)  
# [1] TRUE
```

Retrieve all documents to check the upload

```
f <- mongo.bson.from.list(list("_id" = 0))  ## to ignore the _id field
res <- mongo.find.all(mongo = mongo, ns = ns, fields = f)
toJSON(res, pretty=T)
# [
#   {
#     "id": ["A"],
#     "value1": ["value1_a"]
#   },
#   {
#     "id": ["B"],
#     "value1": ["value1_b"]
#   },
#   {
#     "id": ["C"],
#     "value1": ["value1_c"]
#   },
#   {
#     "id": ["D"],
#     "value1": ["value1_d"]
#   },
#   {
#     "id": ["E"],
#     "value1": ["value1_e"]
#   }
# ]
```

Now, if we want to add our `df2$value2` into those documents, we can bring them back into R to manipulate them, then update the database

```
qry <- list("id" = list("$in" = df2$id))
## mongo shell query: db.test.find({"id" : { "$in" : ["A", "B", ..., ]}})
qry <- mongo.bson.from.list(qry)
f <- list("_id" = 0)
res <- mongo.find.all(mongo = mongo, 
                      ns = ns,
                      query = qry,
                      fields = f)

dt_res <- rbindlist(res)

## set our df2 to data.table, and join onto dt_res
setDT(df2)

## add a new row to df2, with a new id, to check the update.upsert works
df2 <- rbindlist(list(df2, data.table(id = "Z", value2 = "value2_z")))

dt_res <- dt_res[ df2, on="id"]  ## left join to keep our 'z' row
dt_res
#    id   value1   value2
# 1:  A value1_a value2_a
# 2:  B value1_b value2_b
# 3:  C value1_c value2_c
# 4:  D value1_d value2_d
# 5:  E value1_e value2_e
# 6:  Z       NA value2_z
```

We can now update the database with these new values using [`udpate` and `upsert`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dt_res)){

  crit <- mongo.bson.from.list(list("id" = dt_res[i, id]))
  d <- c(dt_res[i, ])
  mongo.update(mongo = mongo, 
               ns = ns, 
               criteria = crit, 
               objNew = d, 
               flags = c(mongo.update.upsert))    
}
```

Check the documnets have been udpated by returning everything

```
f <- mongo.bson.from.list(list("_id" = 0))  ## to ignore the _id field
res <- mongo.find.all(mongo = mongo, ns = ns, fields = f)
toJSON(res, pretty=T)

# [
#   {
#     "id": ["A"],
#     "value1": ["value1_a"],
#     "value2": ["value2_a"]
#   },
#   {
#     "id": ["B"],
#     "value1": ["value1_b"],
#     "value2": ["value2_b"]
#   },
#   {
#     "id": ["C"],
#     "value1": ["value1_c"],
#     "value2": ["value2_c"]
#   },
#   {
#     "id": ["D"],
#     "value1": ["value1_d"],
#     "value2": ["value2_d"]
#   },
#   {
#     "id": ["E"],
#     "value1": ["value1_e"],
#     "value2": ["value2_e"]
#   },
#   {
#     "id": ["Z"],
#     "value1": {},
#     "value2": ["value2_z"]
#   }
# ]
```

Note this includes our new 'z' id

Comment: Very useful. Would it be possible to do a bulk write to Mongo rather than looping over all the rows in the data frame?

Comment: @Iain - At the moment I'm not sure on how to do a bulk **update** without the loop. I'd be interested to know if you find one!. How well does this solution as it is scale to your full data set?